# Can I have a method argument typed "this class"?

Tags: java, method-signature

I want to have an argument of type "this class" in an interface's method signature, so that any class, for example `MyClass`, implementing it will have that method with an argument of type `MyClass`.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public thisClass myMethod(thisClass other);
    ...
}
```

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    // has to reference this class in the implementation
    public MyClass myMethod(MyClass other){
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this possible, or should I just bind the argument with the interface and have each implementation check for it?

Comment: Nice formatting. Had to look up the source to see how you did it. Awesome.

Comment: I don't see what you're impressed with, but thanks. :)

Comment: I previously thought that you couldn't italicize in a code block. You used pre/code instead of MarkDown indentation. Nothing impressive, perhaps, but I did learn from you, thus my sincerest gratitude.

Comment: you should check the jdk or google collections lib for the pattern you are looking for.  I think you might be after something like Comparable.

Comment: @poly: I just opened the Markdown help page, read "Indent four spaces to create an escaped <pre><code> block", but just saw "<pre><code>" and used that. :)
Then I wanted to emphasize some things with asterisks and got even better results (I'm loving this format)!
So, completely unintended on my part, but you're very welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
   public T myMethod(T other);
   ...
}

public class MyClass implements MyInterface<MyClass> {
   // has to reference this class in the implementation
   public MyClass myMethod(MyClass other){
      ...
   } 
}
```

Comment: Hmm. It looks pretty clunky, but it does exactly what I wanted. I'll probably end up using this, thanks.

Comment: public class Foo implements MyInterface<Bar> {
  public Bar myMethod(Bar other) {
    // this isn't what you want is it?
  }
}

Comment: I will be writing any classes that implement this myself, so I'll make sure I don't do that. I wasn't looking for a way to enforce this, just wondering if it's doable without if checks in the method. (Though I guess in both cases it comes down to preconditions)

Answer (score 3):

This somewhat enforces that T is the class that implements the interface:

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends MyInterface<T>> {
   public T myMethod(T other);
   ...
}
```

Comment: It does not.  Consider (1) abstract class MyImpl1 implements MyInterface <MyImpl1> { }; (2) abstract class MyImpl2 implements MyInterface <MyImpl1> { }.  The second does not do what High Five wants.

Comment: I added a 'somewhat' qualifier. I think that it's as close as you can get to what High Five wants.

Comment: Once again, I will be writing these myself, so I don't need that bound, or encounter (2). I was just wondering if it's doable without if checks in the method.